# 90s(?) movie with an army of kids in space and "God" in a foggy white room

Tags: story-identification, movie, spaceship, space

When I was about 7 in 2009 I watched a movie from a VHS tape that I had also watched a couple years before. I believe it was released in the 1990s.

In this live-action movie, I remember there being an army of kids on a space craft. There was a "God" or leader in a foggy white room, who was pretty old. At the end of the movie, two of the adult characters kiss as the movie ends.

**Additional notes from from what I remember:**
All the characters were white
All characters were human looking
The goal of the movie was to get the man out of the white room

**What I know the movie isn't:**
The Fifth Element,
Total Recall,
Gattaca,
Galaxy Quest,
Armageddon,
Starship Troopers,
Event Horizon,
Star Wars: Episode I – The Phantom Menace,
Screamers,
Stargate,
Spaced Invaders,
Alien Intruder,
The Arrival,
The Puppet Masters,
Abraxas, Guardian of the Universe,
Solar Crisis,
Mars Attacks,
Moon 44,
Alien 3,
Alien: Resurrection,
Dead Space,
Lifepod,
Star Trek: First Contact,
Star Trek VI: The Undiscovered Country,
Star Trek Generations,
Star Trek: Insurrection,
Lost in Space,
Muppets From Space,
Virus,
Space Truckers,
Soldier,
Apollo 13,
Wing Commander,
Contact, and
Crossworlds

**Other:**
This movie was suitable enough to show to second graders at the time. I had first watched the movie in Syria when I was about 5. The second time I saw it was when I had been walking on a street with my brother, when I found it laying infront of a house. I had remembered the movie from the cover alone, and my school used to movies once a month to the whole school. After one of the movies had ended, I went to one of the teachers to ask them to play it the next time. During then, I knew very little English, and now I assume they thought the movie was the school's. Fastforward about a month, we watch that same movie that I gave them. Ever since then I haven't seen it, or heared of it.

Comment: Hey there, that's a great start. But can you take a look at https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question/9337#9337 and add any detail you can think it of. It will all help someone answer the question.

Comment: Were the adult figures part of it throughout? Grownup kids? Characters introduced near the end?

Comment: Probably not [The Space Children](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Film/TheSpaceChildren) either, from 1958.

Comment: I don't remember where the adult characters were during the film. I just remember them kissing at the end.

Answer (score 3):

I'll just toss this out there though it is probably wrong: it sounds a bit like *[Silversun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silversun)*, an Australian TV series (not a movie) made in 2004.

> Silversun is a science fiction children's television series made in Australia by the Australian Broadcasting Corporation (ABC). The show features the adventures of the adolescent members of the crew of the Star Runner, an interstellar spaceship carrying a cargo of 550 cryonically suspended colonists ("cryons") to their new home, the Silver Sun.
>
> In the year 2052, the Star Runner and its crew are two years into their 90-year journey to a livable planet 45 light years from Earth. The crew's goal is to get the "New Settlers" safely to the Silver Sun and begin a colony there. Because of the 90-year-length of the journey, the crew are mostly teenagers who will take over command of the Star Runner as the adults get older.

Comment: Why does it sound like *Silversun*?

Comment: white kids in space with a small number of adults.

Comment: You may want to explain that in your answer. :)